# How to reduce brackets in nested JSON in Django Rest

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm solving the problem with Django Rest Framework. The issue is too many brackets in my nested JSON.

I need connect my rest API with client and is necessary make this (or something similar) to speed up client side.

This is my output:

```
[
    {
        "1": {
            "name": "Company 1",
            "data": [
                {
                    "1": {
                        "name": "Place brno",
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "2": {
                                    "name": "Device 1",
                                    "data": [
                                        {
                                            "5": {
                                                "name": "revize 5",
                                                "category": 0
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "6": {
                                                "name": "rev rev",
                                                "category": 0
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "4": {
                                    "name": "Device 3",
                                    "data": [
                                        {
                                            "8": {
                                                "name": "revize 4",
                                                "category": 0
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "9": {
                                                "name": "revize 7",
                                                "category": 2
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "4": {
                        "name": "Place r",
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "3": {
                                    "name": "Device 2",
                                    "data": [
                                        {
                                            "3": {
                                                "name": "revize 2",
                                                "category": 2
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "4": {
                                                "name": "revize 3",
                                                "category": 3
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "11": {
                                                "name": "revision 33",
                                                "category": 0
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

But I need something like this:

```
[
    {
        "1": {
            "name": "Company 1",
            "data": {
                    "1": {
                        "name": "Place brno",
                        "data": {
                                "2": {
                                    "name": "Device 1",
                                    "data": {
                                            "5": {...},
                                            "6": {...}
                                    }
                                },
                                "4": {
                                    "name": "Device 3",
                                    "data": {
                                            "8": {...},
                                            "9": {...}
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    },
                    "4": {
                        "name": "Place r",
                        "data": {
                                "3": {
                                    "name": "Device 2",
                                    "data": {
                                            "3": {...},
                                            "4": {...},
                                            "11": {...}
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Here is my code from serializers.py:

```
class SBRevisionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='revision_type.category')

    class Meta:
        model = Revision
        fields = ('name', 'category')

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {
            obj.id: super(SBRevisionSerializer, self).to_representation(obj),
        }


class SBDeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = SBRevisionSerializer(source='revision_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('name', 'data')

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {
            obj.id: super(SBDeviceSerializer, self).to_representation(obj),
        }


class SBPlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = SBDeviceSerializer(source='device_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Place
        fields = ('name', 'data')

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {
            obj.id: super(SBPlaceSerializer, self).to_representation(obj),
        }



class SBCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = SBPlaceSerializer(source='place_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name', 'data')


    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {
            obj.id: super(SBCompanySerializer, self).to_representation(obj),
        }
```

Any advice, please?

Comment: Please add some context/explanation instead of trying to get around quality filter

Comment: description edited